# Best colors for polls

Tags: android, color, poll

I've developed a polls android application.

Employees fill polls house by house at the door, and they complain about app is difficult to see.

Which color would be better(for background, text, buttons..) to make polls on street?

Thank you in advance for your advices.

Comment: You could at least show the colors you use currently :)

Comment: Well, what specifically are they complaining about? Why don't you ask them what they think would be better? They are the ones you need to please after all.

Answer (score 4):

Did you gain an understanding of how and where users are using your android app?
What you are looking for is not necessarily colors but accessibility & readability.
Please refer to this article for more details https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/04/designing-accessibility-inclusion/